# Setting an ActionBar button visibility to GONE

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-button

I have a toolbar with some actionbar buttons. I would like the camera icon button **NOT to appear** if the
Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21.

in the following menu file I define the actionbar buttons:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>

<item
    android:id="@+id/addons"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_box_black_24dp"
    android:title="camera"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>


<item
    android:id="@+id/hellosearch"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    android:title="camera"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

//inside the MainActivity I override the method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.addons:
            //we are requesting to purchase something:
            Log.d("billing009","trying to start a purchase!! user has accesss(subs): "+user_has_autorenew_subs+
                    " didFind :: " + didFindTotalAccess);

          showPurchaseDialog(styled_title);
            //inHouseMethod_StartPurchase();
            break;

        case R.id.hellosearch:
            mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
```

***HOWEVER***, this method gets called when the user clicks on one of the actionbar buttons.

How can I use the toolbar object created inside onCreate: to get a hold of the Camera icon(ActionBar button), so I can set its visibility to GONE if the Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21  ?

```
//inside onCreate
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that inside **onCreateOptionsMenu** like

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu_xml, menu);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
           MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.idOfYourMenuItem);
           item.setVisible(false);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: that looks correct. Let me try that. But, how can I get the 'menu'?

Comment: I'm trying now!

Answer (score 1):

Put this method in your Activity

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuItem camera = menu.findItem(R.id.addons);      
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) 
    {           
        camera.setVisible(true);
    }
    else
    {
        camera.setVisible(false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

> onPrepareOptionsMenu Prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. This is called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. You can use this method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise dynamically modify the contents.

`onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called once.
`onPrepareOptionsMenu()` is called every time the menu opens.

**From the onCreateOptionsMenu() documentation:**

> This is only called once, the first time the options menu is
> displayed. To update the menu every time it is displayed, see
> onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu).

Comment: I think OP only needs this to be called once though, if the device is below api 21 they can just _always_ hide it, there wouldn't be a need to call this multiple times